Css grid with auto item height
I want to create a grid layout that will have 2 items on each row and the grid should respect each item height depending by the text inside.


.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr); 
    gap: 2px;
}

.item {
    display: flex;
    padding: 18px;
    align-items: start;
    width: 180px; /* Ensure item takes full width of the column */
    align-self: baseline;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1.alasdn nsasdklnaskldasdlkajslkdmkl  asd  Heloo sakjdans dnasnd nas dn asnd </div>
    <div class="item">2. Heloo sakjdans  </div>
    <div class="item">3. sakjdans dnasnd nas dn snd </div>
    <div class="item">4. Heloo sakjdans dnasnd nas dn asnd </div>
    <div class="item">5. Heloodn asnd </div>
    <div class="item">6. Heloodn asnd  Heloodn asnd  Heloodn asnd </div>
</div>



In my code the 4-th item should stay directly beneath 2-nd, but there is a space.  How to get rid of that space and to align every item according it's space?  note: I know that there are options to hardcode the item height using css, but the idea is that every item could have  a dynamic space whichis not known, because data will come from an API and i don't know what content will be in every item.

That's not how CSS-Grid works or is supposed to work.  What you're looking for is called "Masonry Grid" or "Masonry Layout".

This isn’t a grid. You may find column-count useful.
